# Add Linear-layout to Linear-layout in android Dynamically

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I have data like this

```
 <LinearLayout> ===> vertical
     <LinearLayout> ===>Horizontal
       <TextView>    <TextView>  <TextView>    <TextView>
    <LinearLayout> ===>Horizontal
      <TextView>    <TextView>  <TextView>    <TextView>
    <LinearLayout> ===>Horizontal
      <TextView>    <TextView>  <TextView>    <TextView>

 <LinearLayout>
```

How to add these layouts dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: This is not to much difficult. You need to set `LayoutParams` for all `LinearLayout` and add view according to your requirement.

Comment: not much difficult can also created coustem listview

Answer (score 0):

I will help you with the code i have done. Note that i will not code for you (still helping someone's from SO for now). Feel free if you have any question.

Here, i add a `spinner` and `button` on a `linear layout` in the `onClick`, all dynamically :

```
    else if(v == btnAddChild)
    {
        LinearLayout dynamicLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.weight = 1.0f;
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
        dynamicLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        dynamicLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        int layoutId = totalDynamicChild + 1000; //dynamicLayout always have dynamic spinnser's id + 1000 to avoid same id
        dynamicLayout.setId(layoutId);

        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(params);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinChildAdapter);
        spinner.setId(totalDynamicChild);   
        spinnderIdList.add(totalDynamicChild);

        ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
        btn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_delete));
        btn.setBackgroundResource(0);
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
        int btnId = totalDynamicChild + 2000; //btn always have dynamic spinnser's id + 2000 to avoid same id
        btn.setId(btnId);

        dynamicLayout.addView(spinner);
        dynamicLayout.addView(btn);
        parentSpinner.addView(dynamicLayout);
        totalDynamicChild++;
```

And this is how i retrieve the `spinner's` value :

```
    for(int i = 0; i < totalDynamicChild; i++)
    {
        Spinner s = (Spinner)findViewById(spinnderIdList.get(i));
        postParam.put("child_id[" + i + "]", "example");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one xml for vertical LinearLayout with ScrollView as parent so whenever LinearLayout no of child is more it will apply scroll.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Another xml for vertical LinearLayout child which contain 4 TextView in Horizontal LinearLayout.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Now how to add item to vertical LinearLayout :

```
private LinearLayout container;
private Context context;
private int size=3;
private int counter=1;

context = this;
container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
     View view  = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_item,null);
     TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     TextView textView3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
     TextView textView4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

     textView1.setText(String.valueOf(counter++));
     textView2.setText(String.valueOf(counter++));
     textView3.setText(String.valueOf(counter++));
     textView4.setText(String.valueOf(counter++));

     view.setTag((i+1));
     view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf((Integer)v.getTag()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
     });
     container.addView(view);
}
```